# How to add global CSS to all webpages without installing any plugin?

Tags: php, css, apache

Version **6.3** core website; no plugins, no themes, no customizations whatsoever. Plain core website which should stay plain core.

I want to add global CSS that will effect all webpages but without installing or creating any plugin and without creating any sub-theme or child-theme. The website should stay "core".

I don't mind editing any core file directly because the CSS I want to add will automatically be re-added to it after each update, so each time an update deletes it, it will be brought back by a Bash script injecting this code in the end of that file, right after the update.

My question is, what is the best file to inject this CSS to and how would you recommend injecting it?
A side question is can this be done from a PHP file somehow, like appending some
`<style>`
CONTENT
`</style>`
into the `<head>` tag, directly from **the last PHP file being processed**?

Comment: Put it in the .css file in your theme.

Comment: Can you create a child theme then put the css in the main stylesheet?

Comment: modifying WP core directly is not the way to do it, completely unnecessary, and extreme bad practice. it means all your changes are destroyed on update, and flagged as a security problem by antivirus and your hosts security. Checksumming the files is a common practice. The same is true if you modify a theme you didn't build yourself. Also this stack is for developers not end users, and there are ways to do this just by clicking around in the GUI. _Both the site editor and the customizer can be used to write CSS without making any changes to files at all_. But I suspect this is an X Y question

Comment: @TomJNowell I have explained why updates are not a problem in this particular case. The site is pluginless, no "anti virus" of any sort runs on that site. I **intentionally** want to do this is part of learning how PHP works.

Comment: @SavPhill I can but I intentionally don't.

Comment: doing it the right way will teach you more about PHP than doing it the wrong way, if the goal is to provide a way to test and learn PHP then there are better safer ways to do that then editing WP core files. A lot of WP core itself is written in a particular way for historical reasons and backwards compatibility, so modifying it directly is not a good way to learn PHP. Note that any answer you get will try to answer your question as it's written, not your problem.

Comment: @TomJNowell if at all, I try it on a plain core without any real content (lorem ipsum content). To learn how to add "the last CSS from PHP" I would even pay money to learn it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is to have a PHP file where you can insert CSS into the header of all pages then what you need is a plugin, one of your own creation, not one you install.

Create a `.php` file in the plugins folder, e.g. `templaters-plugin.php` and insert this:

```php
<?php
/*
Plugin name: Templaters test plugin
*/
```

Then you can add PHP to that file.

If you want to add arbitrary HTML to a location then you'll need to use filters. Not using filters will break stuff in weird and unexpected ways, which is very bad for your stated goal of learning PHP.

For example, you can use the WordPress APIs to enqueue a CSS file, or add inline scripts, but you can also add HTML to the header, e.g.:

```php
add_action( 'wp_head', function() {
    echo '<!-- I appear in the head tag -->';
} );
```

As for your stated goal of injecting PHP into a file via bash, this won't work, and can never work. The problem is WordPress is a CMS, it has systems and ways of doing things, so there is no "last PHP file" to inject your code into, it's a dynamic system not a chain of files executed in a specific order. Even then, WordPress has shutdown handlers, so even if you did manage to locate a last file for a specific path, it's no guarantee that other code won't run anyway.

---

The irony is, the closest thing to what you wanted, is the very thing you said you did not want, **a theme template.** A theme of your own creation that only contained an `index.php` fits 99% of all your requirements, and in a lot of cases is indeed the last file processed. You could put the entire HTML structure in one file, and experiment to your hearts content in an environment that behaves more like a classic PHP application, including appending to it with a bash file if you so chose.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the hook `wp_head` to print css and javascript to the `<head>` tag. In your case I would create a 1 file plugin where you have the hook that injects the styling.

```
add_action('wp_head', function(){
  echo '<style>';
    echo 'a{ color: hotpink; }';
  echo '</style>';
});
```

More info: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/